# HTTP secure cookie is showing a warning in Firefox

Tags: http, go, firefox, cookies

When using this code snippet in Go

```
    cookie := http.Cookie{
        Name:  "token",
        Value: token.Key,
        Expires:  token.Claims.Expires.Time(),
        Path: "/",
        Secure:   true,
        HttpOnly: true,
        Domain:   "mydomain.net",
        SameSite: http.SameSiteStrictMode,
    }
    http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
```

I get the following warning in Firefox

```
Cookie “token” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite
```

Edit

When I view the header before sending the response I see

```
[token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJkb21haW4iOiJzZWN1cmUubG9jYWwuaG9tbGlzaC5uZXQiLCJleHAiOjE2MDczNjYwMTkuMjYyNzIyLCJpYXQiOjE2MDczNjUxMTkuMjYyNzIyLCJpZCI6MSwibmJmIjoxNjA3MzY1MTE4LjI2MjcyMiwic3ViIjoicGhvbWxpc2gifQ.NPvtLiBIR3luRV5O2sgZyksUperDDaikDv4TMMDiLYvuHfYz4on7V09PhHSA2LQ5evKKtwwLrRVPFvqqoEf9rUOQPUnXLf7P-FLzShpI7neRpu0YwzcdgmUA-phTHaXAkr6havuQWlJItt-xhG6crq4p1Cb2oSCt5p0o8ncIQXXcdmdHHaeHLwxQSzu5x0EkcjiPFyRFPYxj-S1eMXnVEQTPqWa5tESVCwU6n-QnBAQ2RT3j0gQLEKZGERKEydKHDdiBDZ9d2LZSjinp0YJ1mw2BmpMt40sJcXmBKpR_8-M_xWvMK_MbL_GDYMEGsofyJNsPBFE31fHr94i81WnEqJpgZStoA7B2PfOCpKAr-c_DeVZ3THDlMnt1RQ72Fi25tDJx6_yKV13AJskqu9D2yQgcy6vqiS2auDpmLv13X385JG7uGjKYTJvc0rWr_AuozHnfn9sKj-3yb-tWSpSwIKCMEwKB_Ta0sBxGhokHQmhV2x-S3fP9HBAr06p50rufKPbHJCcsLA2YHcPBZivVRhM3FE1H6WM_xeWwMx9Xi-yJjmNPOX5uDFyf-VurTTbxwScWzXXYwTTYkh4Mmf5AdigQ4J9HVh8WLv-nRfsSVjM_tbTP9CiieGBfyA1Upv4CXfafBdKZLrZvrUs6lu-NUc1to5dIckpJlJebI-0S5yc; Path=/; Domain=mydomain.net; Expires=Mon, 07 Dec 2020 18:33:39 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict]"}
```

Note: mydomain.net is the domain of my website, changed in the post to not give away my bits.  This is being done with https and valid certificates.

How can I make a cookie that Firefox will accept as secure?

Edit

After inspecting the javascript I found a line where I was experiementing left in the code:

```
document.cookie = "token=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
```

Comment: Please include the Set-Cookie header sent from your Go code to Firefox. Are you sure you set this cookie via a https connection: You cannot set Secure cookies via http. The error looks strange as Strict is the uncritical mode (None and default changed semantics).

Comment: Volker- added to the post.

Comment: What do you see on the FF side? It is unlikely that your described setup results in this warning.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me Volker.  Please see my latest edit.  Would you care to get credit by answering the question by stating 'don't do that'?

Comment: Glad you found the problem! One more tiny hint: Setting Expires in a SetCookie header is okay and probably fine if your claim also has expire times but for all other cases setting MaxAge is simpler and less error prone (less data in the wire, no timezone issue and no clock skew issues).

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I did as you recommend for the cookie since Expires is in the claims.  I'm using expires to issue a new token/cookie when the existing token is about to expire.

Answer (score 0):

I had a javascript debug statement which was setting an invalid cookie which was initiating the firefox warning.

Always check your code!